# GDAL PostgreSQL shapefile import "Unable to find driver 'PostgreSQL"

Tags: gdal, postgresql, database

I have seen a number of posts similar to this but with no resolution.

I am experimenting with GDAL commands and am fairly new to it however when using a PostgreSQL database connection I am getting the following errors:

> FAILURE: Unable to open datasource `PG:host=127.0.0.1 port=5432
>   dbname=postgres user=postgres password=*******' with the following
>   drivers. 
>   (Lists all drivers)

or

> ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -update -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='cadcorp' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='********'" C:\Users\tommyh\Desktop\data\merged.shp -nlt POLYGON -nln gdaltestupload -progress
```

when I run **gdalinfo --formats** the list doesn't PostgreSQL so I guess I can see why the PostgreSQL connection isn't working compared to when I use a SQL Server connection MMSQLSpatial which is in the formats list.

I have set the environment variables:

GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data

GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins

My GDAL version is:

gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20

Running through the command prompt on Windows 10.

Any ideas on what I may be missing or need to do?

Comment: Do have installed postgres on your machine =  localhost?

Comment: @kurt Yes, I have also tried with 127.0.0.1

Comment: did you install the postgres-server-software from https://www.postgresql.org/ on your machine?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.6 is installed and is fully functioning, the database holds multiple datasets which have been added into other GIS applications for styling and editing. I do not believe this is a postgreSQL software issue. The software has been downloaded from: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Comment: gdalinfo --formats is listing the raster drivers, check `ogrinfo --formats`instead.

Comment: @user30184 Running ogrinfo --formats  has PGDUMP -vector- (w+v): PostgreSQL SQL dump whereas the original gdalinfo --formats has  PostGISRaster -raster- (rws): PostGIS Raster driver. Do you have an additional driver ? do you know which is missing?

Comment: Looking at my OSGeo4W shell and running ogrinfo --formats shows a driver for PostgreSQL -vector- (rw+): PostgreSQL/PostGIS, the GDAL version of this is 2.3.2 which is nearly a year newer however the notes on https://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html suggests that you can use the postgis dump connection on earlier versions that >= 1.8.0. However I am on 2.2.3 anyhow, I will uninstall and re-try.

Comment: GDAL version 2.4.0, release 2018/12/14 is still not showing the "PostgresSQL" driver in ogrinfo --formats...........

Comment: `Gdalinfo --formats` is not relevant for you. PostGISRaster is a system for storing raster data into PostgreSQL. OGR driver `PGDUMP` is not the driver that you want to use. Driver `PostgreSQL -vector- (rw+)`  is the one that you need. From page https://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html you can see that PGDUMP is compiled by default. The problem that you had comes obviously from the GDAL build that you are using. It is compiled without PostgreSQL driver and then it just can't work directly with PostGIS. PGDUMP is an offline driver, it writes a text file that can be imported with PostgreSQL tools.

Comment: So why don't you use your OSGeo4?

Comment: @user30184 I think I will have to, I am still curious as to why my installs do not include the "PostgreSQL" driver. But yes I guess I will use OSGeo4 for now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You must ask from those who made the GDAL build that you are using why they desided to build it without PostgreSQL. It is a configuration option.